# How do I prove that the distribution of $x_t$ in $x_t=x_{t-1}e^{-μt}+ θ(1-e^{-μΔt}) + \int_{t-1}^t e^{-μ(t-s)}\sigma dB_s $ is a normal distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, gaussian

$B_s$ is brownian motion. Because $\int_{t-1}^t e^{-μ(t-s)}\sigma dB_s  $ has a Brownian component, it is normally distributed according to Taylor & Karin 1998 's Introduction to Stochastic Modelling.

The above equation is derived from the ornstein uhlenbeck model:
$$dx_{t}= μ(θ-x_t)dt+\sigma B_t  $$

and the above equation is  $x_t$ given  $x_{t-1}$.

Based on Leung & Li 2016's Optimal Mean Reversion Trading, the distribution of $x_t$ given  $x_{t-1}$ under the Ornstein Uhlenbeck model is  normally distributed with
$$E[x_t|x_{t-1}]=x_{t-1}e^{-μΔt}+ θ(1-e^{-μΔt})$$

$$ Var(x_t|x_{t-1})= \frac{\sigma^2}{2μ}(1-e^{-2μΔt})$$

How can I prove its normally distrbuted? I already derived the mean and variance in my own time, but I still dont know how to prove its normally distributed.

I saw this question with its answer:

[Ornstein-Uhlenbeck stochastic process and gaussian process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521215/ornstein-uhlenbeck-stochastic-process-and-gaussian-process)

"Depending on the precise context, we might be able to use the following theorem:

```
If :[0,]→ℝ
```

is nonrandom and  is a Gaussian process for 0≤≤, then ()+ is a Gaussian process for 0≤≤"

Can this be a clue? Please help, thanks!

Comment: Hint : $x_t=x_0e^{-\mu t}+\theta(1-e^{-\mu t})+\int_0^te^{-\mu(t-s)}\sigma\,dB_s$. This is normally distributed when $x_0$ is not random.

Comment: What book/journal can I read for that reference? The initial condition for this problem is $x_{t-1}$ not $x_0$, is it still fine?

Comment: It is. When you ask for the distribution of $\mathbb E[x_t|x_s]$ *given* $x_s$ you pretend that $x_s$ is not random. Also: by the Markov property and the martingale property: $\mathbb E[x_t|x_s]=\mathbb E[x_t|{\cal F}_s]=x_0e^{-\mu t}+\theta(1-e^{-\mu t})+\int_0^se^{-\mu(t-u)}\sigma\,dB_u$ which is also seen to be normal even without assuming that $x_s$ is given.

Comment: Those kind of stochastic integrals (with deterministic integrands) are called Wiener integrals